How do I make std::function<void(X)> accept lambdas where the first argument is a polymorphic subtype of X?
Suppose I have a generic Event class like this:
// Event (Generic)
struct Event {
    // Event type
    std::string m_type;

    // c-tor
    Event(const std::string& type) : m_type(type) { /* empty */ }

    // d-tor (polymorphic)
    virtual ~Event() = default;
};

Suppose I have a KeyEvent class which sub-classes Event:
// Event (Keyboard)
struct KeyEvent : Event {
    // Key 
    char m_key;

    // Key down or up
    bool m_down;

    // c-tor
    KeyEvent(char key, bool down) 
        : Event(down ? "keydown" : "keyup")
        , m_key(key)
        , m_down(down) { /* empty */ }
};

Suppose I have a generic Component class which can listen to and trigger events defined above
// Component (listens to events)
class Component {

    // ...

    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::function<void(const Event&)>>> m_events;

    // ...

public:

    // Listen to event
    void listen(const std::string& type, std::function<void(const Event&)> callback) {
        m_events[type].push_back(callback);
    }

    // Trigger event
    void trigger(const Event& event) {
        auto it = m_events.find(event.m_type);
        if (it != m_events.end()) {
            for (auto& callback : m_events[event.m_type]) {
                callback(event);
            }
        }
    }
};

I would like to be able to add a key down listener in the following fashion.
int main() {
    Component c;

    // Listen to key down event
    c.listen("keydown", [](const KeyEvent& keyEvent){
        std::cout << "You pressed '" << keyEvent.m_key << "'!\n";
    });

    // Trigger event
    c.trigger(KeyEvent('A', true));
}

However this causes the following compiler error
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:65:13: error: cannot convert ‘main()::<lambda(const KeyEvent&)>’ to ‘std::function<void(const Event&)>’
   65 |     c.listen("keydown", [](const KeyEvent& event) {
      |     ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   66 | 
      |              
   67 |     });
      |     ~~       
main.cpp:46:76: note:   initializing argument 2 of ‘void Component::listen(const string&, std::function<void(const Event&)>)’
   46 |     void listen(const std::string& type, std::function<void(const Event&)> callback) {
      |                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~

I can readily solve the issue by using [](const Event&){ ... }, rather than [](const KeyEvent&){ ... }, and then explicitly dynamic_cast'ing Event into KeyEvent:
int main() {
    Component c;

    // Listen to event
    c.listen("keydown", [](const Event& event){
        auto& keyEvent = dynamic_cast<const KeyEvent&>(event);
        std::cout << "You pressed '" << keyEvent.m_key << "'!\n";
    });

    // Trigger event
    c.trigger(KeyEvent('A', true));
}

However, I'm wondering if rather there is a way of leaving [](const KeyEvent&){ ... } in main() function alone and modifying the second parameter of void Component::listen(const std::string&, std::function<void(const Event&)>) such that it would allow for such lambda functions after all? Perhaps, I can wrap the callback argument in a wrapper function [](const Event&){ ... } where it can do the downcast before adding it to adding it to m_events?

Please provide a [mre].

If you did what you wanted, then the callsite would change from callback(event); to if (auto keyEvent = dynamic_cast<KeyEvent const*>(&event)) callback(*keyEvent); ... which is probably undesirable.

For me your code design looks bad. Maybe you should read about visitor pattern and double dispatch and then write code again. It is hard to fix your code since you didn't explain what it should do (you just explained how you wish to implement it). It also annoying you have to ways to express what event is expected: by type itself and string name.

Because the current lack of introspection in C++, you have to help a bit, but you can boil it down a lot from the cast you propose on the caller site.
    //template <std::derived_from<Event> T> only C++20
    template <typename T>
    void listen(std::string const& type, std::function<void(T)> callback) {
        auto wrapper = [callback = std::move(callback)](Event const& ev) {
            callback(static_cast<T const&>(ev));
        };
        m_events[type].push_back(std::move(wrapper));
    }

This allows you to have a call like this.
    c.listen<KeyEvent>("keydown", [](const KeyEvent& keyEvent){
    //       ^^^^^^^^
        std::cout << "You pressed '" << keyEvent.m_key << "'!\n";
    });

Note that with the C++20 concept std::derived_from you can always static_cast while with C++17, as tagged in your OP, you might want to still use dynamic_cast and figure out what to do if someone calls your listen function without a type that is derived from Event.

nice answer, but you can do an extra trick to have the compiler deduce listen template paramter using a helper function https://godbolt.org/z/jEYdsd434
